# BeautifulSoup error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "https://twitter.com/official_YDP09"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

print(Soup.title)
```

and the result is error

```
C:\Users\Yohan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:/Users/Yohan/PycharmProjects/Project/aku pasti bisa.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yohan/PycharmProjects/Project/aku pasti bisa.py", line 7, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\Yohan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 153, in __init__
    builder = builder_class()
  File "C:\Users\Yohan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 39, in __init__
    return super(HTMLParserTreeBuilder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a short fix change print(Soup.title) to print(soup.title)
soup is lowercase.
Try switching to [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) from urllib. Hope this helps if not please let us know.

EDIT 1: Adding image of result[image]

Comment: I have try and the result is :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: check my answer @YohanesDwiPratama since you using python 3 you need to install bs4 again

Answer (score 0):

You have to change that string:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.read(), "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the output,

difference i found was ,
print(soup.title) # here You using capital Soup

if its not solved reinstall your beautifulsoup into proper version. you need version 4.4+ because you using python 3.6+

```
import urllib.request
```

is not required since you already `import urllib`

You're using python3, so install bs4 specifically for your python3 using,

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

if you dont have `pip3` install it using `apt-get install python3-pip`

[image: Output]